# how to fix ImportError: No module named main.models

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv

Disclaimer: I am brand new to coding so this may be a dumb question, but I would LOVE some help

I am trying to get a .py folder uploaded into mysql but it keeps giving me a name error. This is my code, where am I going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('..')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Comics.settings")

from main.models import Comicbook

csv_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__')), "stores.csv")
csv_file = open(csv_file_path, 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

Store = Store.objects.all()

for row in reader:
    new_store = Store
    new_store, created = Stores.objects.get_or_create(state=row['State'])
    new_store.city = row['City']
    new_store.name = row['Name']
    new_store.number = row['Number']

    new_store.save()

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: What is this? is a View? where is this file? can you show your project's folder tree?

Comment: What is `main.models.Comicbook` ? You seem to be trying to import it and not even using it ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some mistakes here.

- You import `Comicbook` but never use it, you could delete this line `from main.models import Comicbook`
- `Store` and `Stores` are never imported.
- Why `new_store = Store.objects.all()` and then change it for other value?

You should check this points.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line:

`from main.models import Comicbook`

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/to/Comics')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Comics.settings")

from main.models import Comicbook #if main is an app inside
```